# R: merge.xts common columns

Tags: r, merge, xts

After a call to `merge.xts` my resulting time-series object has 3 columns named A.1, B.1, C.1. The original xts objects both have A, B, C columns set. I am assuming the merge was performed on all the common columns as per documentation.

I checked the column contents A, B, C and A.1, B.1, C.1. A call to `my.merged[my.merged$A.1 != my.merged$A, ]` returns no rows for all of these columns.

Why the common columns were not collapsed in just one set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?merge.xts` very clearly says that it is "Used to perform merge operation on 'xts' objects by *time* (index)."  Nowhere does it say that the merge is done on common columns.  You probably read that in `?merge`, in reference to the data.frame method.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to avoid the double columns in merge.xts() other than removing them manually after the merge?

Comment: @RobertKubrick: remove them before the merge or remove them after the merge.  It would add a lot of complexity to `merge.xts` to check if columns were equal in two or more objects being merged (e.g. what if the data are the same but the column names are different? what's the tolerance for comparing floating-point numbers? what if the data in columns in two objects are the same, but a similarly named column in a third object is different? etc., etc.).

Answer (score 3):

I think what you may have wanted was `rbind`, not `merge`. I blogged about this, with example data, at http://darrendev.blogspot.jp/2012/08/small-rxts-code-snippets-and-tips.html (see items 6a and 6b).

If you have the same timestamp in both the xts objects you are merging, then you will get duplicate rows. So to get your desired result you then remove duplicates as a post-process step.